# How do I make this jquery popup function reusable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am using this code:
http://jsfiddle.net/xSmNs/

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#lightbox_button').click(function() {
            $('#lightbox').fadeIn('slow');
            $('#lightbox_panel').fadeIn('slow');
        });

        $('#close_lightbox').click(function() {
            $('#lightbox').fadeOut('slow');
            $('#lightbox_panel').fadeOut('slow');
        });

    });
```

To make popups on click of a link. I want multiple links that output different divs. I was going to just make multiple instances of this code (changing the id so that the buttons open their corresponding divs) but I am wondering if there is a more efficient method **using this code**?

Comment: If you've multiple popups use common class on them and bind the event on the class. Also use `data-*` attribute to store related information. Check [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/xSmNs/23/)

Comment: Are you really using jQuery 1.4.4? That's almost 6 years out of date!

Answer (score 0):

You can use $.fn.lightbox as a function itself and apply it on a DOM object.

http://jsfiddle.net/7rfpwctm/2/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.fn.lightbox = function(){
         $(this).click(function() {
        $('#lightbox').fadeIn('slow');
        $('#lightbox_panel').fadeIn('slow');
    });

    $('#close_lightbox').click(function() {
        $('#lightbox').fadeOut('slow');
        $('#lightbox_panel').fadeOut('slow');
    });
        
    };

    
   $('#lightbox_button').lightbox();
    $('#another_lightbox_button').lightbox();

        
});
```

```css
#lightbox_panel 
{ 
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99; 
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px; 
    margin: 30px auto 0;
    background-color: #CCC;
    display: none;
    padding: 10px;
}

#lightbox 
{ 
    z-index: 90;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    top: 0;
}



#close_lightbox 
{
    
}
#lightbox_button{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:100%;
    width:200px;
}

#another_lightbox_button{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:100%;
    width:400px;
}

 .button 
{ 
    position: absolute;
    text-decoration: none; 
    padding: 2px 10px; 
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: inline-block; 
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
   
    
    
    <a href="#" id="lightbox_button">
        <div class="button">button</div>
    </a>
        
      <a href="#" id="another_lightbox_button">
        <div class="button">another button</div>
    </a>
        
    
    <div id="lightbox_panel">
        
        <h1>lightbox panel</h1>
    
        <a href="#" id="close_lightbox">
            <div class="button">close</div>
        </a>
    
    </div>
    
</div>

<div id="lightbox"></div>
```

Something like this helps?

Answer (score 0):

Give the light box button 2 data-attributes, which points to the divs which needs to be popup when clicking on that. Also use a common class for all light box buttons.

```
<a href="#" class="lightbox_button" data-box="#lightbox" data-panel="#lightbox_panel">
        <div class="button" >button</div>
    </a>
```

Then you can re-use the code like,

```
$('.lightbox_button').click(function () {
    $($(this).data("box")).fadeIn("slow");
    $($(this).data("panel")).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xSmNs/26/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this function:

```
function doModal(boxid,show) {
   if (show) {
      $('#'+boxid).fadeIn('slow');
      $('#'+boxid+'_panel').fadeIn('slow');
   } else {
      $('#'+boxid).fadeOut('slow');
      $('#'+boxid+'_panel').fadeOut('slow');
   }
}
```

And then on your buttons or links:

```
<span onclick="doModal('Box1',true)">Open Box 1</span>
<span onclick="doModal('Box2',true)">Open Box 2</span>
```

For closing the boxes:

```
<span onclick="doModal('Box1',false)">Close Box 1</span>
<span onclick="doModal('Box2',false)">Close Box 2</span>
```